# m∗(E)=sup{m∗(K):K⊂E, with K compact} holds even m*(E) = infty?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

The problem is :
Let $E\subset R$ be an arbitrary measurable set.
Then, $m^∗(E) = \sup$ { $m^∗(K): K ⊂ E, K :$ closed and bounded(which means it's compact) }

($m^∗$ is Lebesgue outer measure.)

I know how to solve this problem when $m^*(E) < \infty$
(Also, there was such a nice answer when $m^*(E) < \infty$)
But, it was hard for me to solve this when the measure of E becomes infinite.(And, there was no idea I could find "$m^*(E) = \infty$")

I tried to get $m^*(E) = N $ and make N sufficiently big, so that it goes to infinity. But, since all $K$ is bounded, I don't know if this idea is right.

Could you give me a nicer solution or good tip to solve in infinity?

Comment: Do you know that $m^*(E \cap [-x, x]) \to m^*(E)$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Oh, now I see that skill. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $m^{*}(E)=\infty$. Then, given any $M>0$ there exists $N$ such that $m^{*}(E \cap [-N,N]) >M$. There is a closed and bounded set $K \subseteq  E \cap [-N,N]$ such that $m^{*} (K) >m^{*} (E \cap [-N,N])-\epsilon$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, now I see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote it and accept it by clicking on the tick along side the post. Thanks.

Comment: Why do we require compact sets in the def of inner measure and not just closed ones?